# InputDialog showing up multiple times

Tags: java, swing, text, dialog, paint

I am trying to add text to my paint program, but I have some trouble with it. 
This is what I want: a person clicks somewhere in the frame, an inputdialog shows up where the person can type in their text and after clicking OK, the text will show up at the clicked location.
First of all I get a copy of the dialog showing up at the left upper corner after I pressed OK. Like this: [inputdialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxwm6.jpg)

Second of all: the first time adding text works fine, but the second time the inputdialog shows up twice and I have to fill in the text twice before it shows up on the frame. The third time I have to do it 3 times and so on...

This are parts of my code:

```
    public class MyTexfield implements drawable {

        private double x1, y1, x2, y2;

        public void MyTextfield() {
        }

        public void MyTextfield (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
            this.x1 = x1;
            this.y1 = y1;
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.y2 = y2;
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
            double x = getStartX();
            double y = getStartY();
            String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Your text here", null);
            g.drawString(text, (int)x, (int)y);

        }

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    Color fillColor = null;
    List<drawable> shapesList = new ArrayList<drawable>();
    int prevx;
    int prevy;

    DrawPanel() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // Cast the graphics object to type Graphics2D
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (drawable s : shapesList)
            s.draw(g2d);
    }
    public void addText(int x, int y, int z, int a)
        {
            MyTexfield textField = new MyTexfield();
            shapesList.add(textField);
            textField.setCoordinates(x,y,z,a);
            repaint();
        }
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Lets get something clear immediately!  *Draw* should only be about drawing.  You should never do anything that would put the thread in wait state like open a dialog or something similar.  You should catch the click event in DrawPanel and open the dialog then.  The drawing should, once you know what text goes where, do the drawing of the text if that is what you want.

Comment: Can you add a SSCCE?  The code you show doesn't compile & it's hard to see the workflow.